# Cosmos DB query with JavaScript API v2 query for 1 doc

Tags: javascript, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have an async call chain that looks like this:

```html
getConnections()
  .then(() => addOneNewDoc())
  .then(() => fetchOneDoc());
```

The addNewDoc() works fine and inserts a document. I then use the query capabilities of the API to query for the document in fetchOneDoc().

The call to fetch doc always returns undefined, but I can go see the document in the portal db browser. I've tried sleeping between the calls in case the doc just didn't make it in before the query, but that didn't work either.

```
  const query = `select * from items i where i.id = '${docId}'`;

  const {result: doc} = await connection.container.items.query(query);

      if (!doc) {
          console.log('GOT NO DOCS BACK');
      return;
  }
```

I have validated the query works fine in the portal.

Comment: What's your specific code in `addOneNewDoc` and `fetchOneDoc` function?

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you? Any progress/

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to my sample code:

```
const cosmos = require('@azure/cosmos');
const CosmosClient = cosmos.CosmosClient;

const endpoint = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";                 // Add your endpoint
const masterKey = "***";  // Add the masterkey of the endpoint
const client = new CosmosClient({ endpoint, auth: { masterKey } });
const databaseId = "db";
const containerId = "coll";

async function run() {
    await insertItem(); 
}

async function insertItem(continuationToken) {
    const { container, database } = await init();
    const documentDefinition = { content: 'Hello World!' };

    const { body } = await container.items.create(documentDefinition);
    console.log('Created item with content: ', body.id);
    return await queryItems1(body.id);
}

async function queryItems1(idParam) {
    const { container, database } = await init();
    const querySpec = {
        query: "SELECT r.id,r._ts FROM root r where r.id = '"+ idParam +"'" 
        };
    const queryIterator = await container.items.query(querySpec,null);
    if (queryIterator.hasMoreResults()) {
        const { result: results, headers } = await queryIterator.executeNext();
        console.log(results)
    }   
}
async function init() {
    const { database } = await client.databases.createIfNotExists({ id: databaseId });
    const { container } = await database.containers.createIfNotExists({ id: containerId });
    return { database, container };
}

run().catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```